# How can I multicolor a h1 in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to multicolor a heading in my website. I'm using CSS for the color defining, and using `span` with the class for the text. However, the color doesnt show and there's this space between the different `span` tags when it renders.

[Current HTML and the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xnSg.png)

I tried to remove the `h1` styling (I have styling for the `h1` tag itself) thinking that was the issue. And nope.

oops, forgot to add the code xD

the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>
        Why are you here?
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Akari.css">
</head>

<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>
            <span class="colorRed">
                Ak
            </span>
            <span color="colorDarkRed">
                 a
            </span>
            <span class="colorDarkOrange">
                ri -
            </span>
            <span class="colorRed">
                Play
            </span>
            <span class="colorDarkRed">
                st
            </span>
            <span class="colorGreen">
                ation
            </span>
            <span class="colorDarkOrange">
                3 V
            </span>
            <span class="colorOrange">
                SH
            </span>
            <span class="colorOrange">
                Me
            </span>
            <span class="colorYellow">
                nu
            </span>
            </h1>
            
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <p>
                test
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>


    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="../index.html">
           Back to home
        </a>
    </div>
</html>
```

the CSS:

```css
body
        {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            background-image: url(../images/channels4_banner.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            color: white;
        }
        a:link
        {
            color: rgb(126, 70, 156);
            text-decoration: none
 
        }
     a:visited
        {
            color: rgb(126, 70, 156);
        }
     a:hover
        {
            color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
     a:active
        {
            color: purple;
        }

    .navbar
        {
            background-color: rgb(52, 51, 51);
            overflow: hidden;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 10px;
            opacity: 90%;
        }
    .navbar a 
        {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            color: rgb(126, 70, 156);
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 17px;
        }
    .navbar a:hover 
        {
            background-color: grey;
            color: rgb(55, 37, 58);
            transition: background-color 1s,
                color 1s
        }
    .navbar a.active
        {
            color: white;
        }

h1 
            {
              background-color:  rgb(126, 70, 156);
              opacity: 40%;
            }
colorRed
            {
                color:red;
            }
colorDarkRed
            {
                color:rgb(169, 4, 4);
            }
colorGreen
            {
                color:green;
            }
colorDarkOrange
            {
                color:rgb(162, 107, 4);
            }
colorOrange
            {
                color:orange;
            }
colorYellow
            {
                color:yellow;
            }


main
            {
                
            }
```

The `main` in the CSS is empty for a reason, it will be used when fix this heading issue.

Fixed the spacing issue, still no coloring though.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1wTq.png)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to show some code here. We don't debug images.

Comment: Also show your CSS, which I assume contains styles for the color classes.

Comment: [How to remove the space between inline/inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 0):

### Spacing Issue

Your `<span>` tags technically have a space between them because they are on new lines, that's why you are seeing spaces rendering in between the letters in your `<h1>`.

So instead of:

```html
<span class="colorRed">
  Ak
</span>
<span color="colorDarkRed">
  a
</span>
<span class="colorDarkOrange">
  ri -
</span>
<span class="colorRed">
  Play
</span>
<span class="colorDarkRed">
  st
</span>
<span class="colorGreen">
  ation
</span>
```

Try:

```html
<span class="colorRed">Ak</span><span color="colorDarkRed">a</span><span class="colorDarkOrange">ri -</span><span class="colorRed">Play</span><span class="colorDarkRed">st</span><span class="colorGreen">ation</span>
```

### Color Classes

You should be able to set up the colors like this:

```css
.colorRed {
  color: red;
}
.colorDarkRed {
  color:darkred 
}
/* etc.. */
```

edit: you need to set up your classes with a dot in front of them. So rather than:

```css
colorDarkRed { /* styles */ }
```

Try:

```css
.colorDarkRed { /* styles */ }
```

Comment: To elaborate on a correct answer: `span` is an inline-element. As such a linebreak will have the same effect as a normal space. The solution recommended is one of many possible solutions that however is one of the poorer solutions compared to the others as it potentially si harder to read. [This duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements) is a good summery of other solutions.